# soapUI: How to Assertions of properties

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I would like to verfiy, that `result` -which is comming in the Response/json - is smaller than `maxValue`

The response jason looks like this:

```
{
  
   "result": 4
}
```

I have defined properties as follow:

> result: 4
>
> maxValue: 5

Using `contains Assertions`, I can assert, that `result` equals 4 as follows:

```
"result":"${#TestCase#result}"
```

My Question: How to assert, that `result` < `maxValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [how to assert json in soapui](http://www.robert-nemet.com/2012/08/json-asserting-in-soapui.html).